# Ubuntu 20.04: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 20.04, dependencies

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.  One application does not run any more with the error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have searched this forum and followed the advice and tried: `sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0:amd64`.

I get:

```
Package libssl1.0.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl1.0.0' has no installation candidate
```

I also tried `sudo apt install libssl1.1`, and I get:

```
libssl1.1 is already the newest version (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2).
libssl1.1 set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openmpi-bin : Depends: libopenmpi3 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libopenmpi-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So then I tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install libssl1.1`, but I get:

```
libssl1.1 is already the newest version (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2).
libssl1.1 set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openmpi-bin : Depends: libopenmpi3 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libopenmpi-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I also tried 'E: Unable to locate package libssl1.0' and I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package libssl1.0
```

Finally I tried:

```
sudo apt install --fix-broken
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

However, I still get the same error.  Any ideas before I downgrade to Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Did you enable the repository from which you installed openmpi packages? On OS upgrade process this repo has been disabled as it is third party repository (I think).

Comment: `apt-file search libssl.so.1.0.0` finds it in the **nsight-compute** and **nsight-systems** packages.

Answer (score 41):

I ran into the same issue I think (I had the same error message trying to launch RStudio after upgrading Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04). Here is what worked for me after reading the following page: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libssl1.0.0/download

- Edit the source list `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` to add the following line:
  `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main`
- Then `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install libssl1.0.0`.

I hope t works for you too.

Comment: Perfect. thank you!

Comment: Is it a good advice to suggest installing xenial packages into 20.04? You might end up with a totally broken system all at once in the future, may you? Sounds as extremely dirty advice. I will not try to damage my own 20.04.x installation with this advice.

Comment: Offtopic: Hmm I hope most or all Linuxes will adopt `nix` in the future as it solves all kinds of similar problems.

Comment: you are my hero!

Comment: perfect solution. It works on my 20.04 ubuntu

Comment: Thanks, it worked even in 2022! :P

Comment: This failed for me with `E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' is not signed. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`.

Answer (score 14):

I solved my problem with libssl1.0.0 like this:

I opened http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/ in my browser and download last version of **libssl1.0.0** for my system (for me it was **libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb**)
Then I just install it:

```
sudo gdebi ./libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Cheers for this, but doesn't work for me! I get the following error message: 

This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6)

Comment: Hm... I have Ubuntu 20.04, it was ok. What dependencies does it want?

Comment: Apparently the solution was to download manually via wget and then install with dpkg.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just do clarify for others: `wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.7_amd64.deb` and then `dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.7_amd64.deb`
this did the trick for me on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: But not for me.Today(09/2022) the only solution listed here for 20.04 is to use the link above (http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/)and manually install libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.10_amd64.deb all others solution seem out to date.

Comment: amazing! worked great without having to install xenial packages!! this should be the accepted solution!

Comment: @Westcroft_to_Apse thank you, that did the trick, is there a reason why downloading from the browser doesn't work while downloading it with `wget` seems to work?

Comment: @qwerty_url I didn't say to download by browser. I said to check suitable version by browser. There are many links on that page.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem too. RStudio depends on libssl 1.0.0, while Ubuntu 20.04 distributes the newer libssl 1.1.0.

Here is how to download and install the older version manually:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Hopefully, RStudio will at some point be upgraded to work with the newer version of libssl.

Comment: Please don't suggest to install *.deb.  If there are other .deb files in the directory where the wget downloaded it will attempt to run them as sudo.  Please me careful and prescriptive with fully qualified names.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to install RStudio Server 1.4.1103 on Ubuntu 20.04 and had the "`libssl1.0.0` problem" (Ubuntu 18.04+ uses `libssl1.1` natively). I found the solution [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-server-ubuntu-20-04/64188/12?u=filipezabala) and made some version updates. Check [here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/) for updates.

**Installing libssl1.0.0**

```
$ wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.13_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt install ./libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.13_amd64.deb
```

**Installing RStudio Server 1.4.1103**

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
$ wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/bionic/amd64/rstudio-server-1.4.1103-amd64.deb
$ sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.4.1103-amd64.deb
```

**Finding my local IP (in my case 192.168.0.17)**

```
ip addr show
```

Finally I opened Studio Server in my browser using http://192.168.0.17:8787/.

Comment: file not found on server

Comment: @brauliobo, take a look at the updated link.

Answer (score 1):

I use Debian Buster when I faced the issue like you. I resolved it by doing this:

First I see libssl1.0.0 is not in the Debian Buster APT Repository, it is replace by libssl1.1

Therefore, I add the Jessie APT repository to /etc/apt/source.list by run this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/source.list
```

Paste the Jessie APT Repository:
"deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main"

Save and Exit (Ctrl + s && Ctrl + x)
Run the update:
sudo apt update
Install the libssl1.0.0 package
sudo apt install libssl1.0.0

Re-run rstudio, and it will run successfully.

Comment: Adding a repository of a different distribution is a very bad practice: not only this solution may not work (Packages are distribution dependent), it may also cause a handful of dependencies installation and overall unpredictable results.

Answer (score 1):

I needed the lib for eagle7.7

My solution:

```
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.1 libssl.so.1.0.0
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.1 libcrypto.so.1.0.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hit this link and download "libssl.so.1.0.0" file manually:

https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=jessie&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libssl.so.1.0.0

Comment: no results found